# gcloud repos linked to bitbucket turned read-only

Tags: git, bitbucket, gcloud

I have created a repo in the gcloud source code/developer area that is linked to a repo hosted on bitbucket. This has always worked fine, but recently when I try to do a simple push I get this message:

```
fatal: protocol error: expected sha/ref, got 'The remote repository is a read-only mirror of http://bitbucket.og/[...]. To update, please push there.
```

I don't mind switching to work directly with BitBucket, but I like the idea of continuing to run this thru gcloud if I can. I have unlinked the repo on gcloud and relinked to BitBucket, no luck.

Does this seem familiar to anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a github linked repo.  I ended up just adding a remote for github.  e.g.

```
git remote add github http://github.com/<user>/<repo>
git push github master
```

Doing this, the gcloud repo was mirrored automatically and reflected in the cloud console immediately.